# Android dev and Picasso image library

Tags: android, picasso

I'm new to android dev and am reading about the Picasso library. My question is, does Picasso take care of HTTP requests itself, so no need to create a urlconnection yourself?

Comment: Picasso takes care of the requests by using OkHttp or UrlConnection internally. You can also implement your own Downloader to use other libraries. Disk caching is handled by the network stack.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it takes care of that. For example, if you want to download and display some image ,this code :

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)       //Loading automatically
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)
```

will do the job.